# How to access file info (such as date created,size etc) about a file in iphone?

Tags: iphone, fileinfo

How to access file info (such as date created,size etc) about a file in iphone?i need to sort certain files based on the date of creation,size etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this method:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary* attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                             attributesOfItemAtPath: filePath 
                                              error: &error];
```

You can then query `[attributes fileCreationDate]` or `[attributes fileSize]`. See NSFileManager.h for the `NSFileAttributes` category of `NSDictionary`.